# Evaluate all pronumerals in an arithmetic sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a question like:

```
(2t − 3) + (3t + 1) + (5t + 2) +…
```

or

```
(t − 5) + 3t + (3t + 1) +…
```

I find myself just using trial and error to find the pronumeral that gives a common difference. I feel like that is very time consuming and could possibly be solved with a formula (if there is one).

I know of formulas that find the *nth term* such as:

```
Tn = Tn-1 + d
```

and:

```
Tn = a + (n-1)d
```

I either don't know how to relate these formulas to the questions above or they are not related. Is trial and error the only method here? thanks.